# joining polylines on geometry and attribute

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, spatialite

I have dowloaded an Open street Map shapefile containing streets and their attributes, for my whole country.
I have qgis  and spatialite_gui and a very basic understanding of SQL
The problem I have is that OSM splits roads of the same name according to a variety of factors such as attribute changes , this means our main street is divided into multiple sections. each section has it's own OSM_ID

I wish to join these sections back together ( I don't care about the attributes, except the name) based on their proximity and their names. (My software that will consume this data from another api will determine if the intersecting road terminates at the intersection from the linestring, i.e. it's not just for display purposes.)

I have tried using the qgis-line dissolve method but dissolving on name alone causes a merge between all streets in the country having the same name. eg there are about 30 "Victoria streets".
so I need to merge the streets that have the same name AND have a similar geometry (e.g. within 10-20m )

How/what steps should I take to achieve this, 
I will then want to convert back to a shapefile which will be uploaded to public data server which others can use.

My table is called CentrelinesTBL
with fields

```
osm_id
Highwayname
Speed
Name  ( <--Streetname)
Geometry - looks to be a blob, eg: it appears in the table as "BLOB sz =384 geometry" but if I use blob explore I can see...

{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[175.4088968683988,
-39.40728494205201,0],[175.4091779512512,-39.407522943693,0],
[175.4107932119636,-39.40868038774494,0]]}
```